# Role based authorization in hosted ASP.NET-Core-Blazor-WebAssembly-App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I tried to use roles in my blazor project. I more or less orientated myself by this https://code-maze.com/using-roles-in-blazor-webassembly-hosted-applications/ tutorial

I created roles in the database and everything, like login and such, worked. I added

```
services.AddIdentityServer().AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDBContext>(opt =>
        {
            opt.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
            opt.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
        });
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("role");
```

in the Startup.cs file. To create a "role" claim for my user, but when I log in I don't see a role claim.

```
s_hash: nz4meiUsDlXBa8pOfipRmw
sid: 792E67E7F29DF24F13045EECD0DCC6C2
sub: e999a53a-8c76-4737-a202-dabe9e9eeceb
auth_time: 1628245115
idp: local
amr: ["pwd"]
preferred_username: waiter2000@gmx.de
name: waiter2000@gmx.de
```

The problem is that I have not been able to use role-based authorization for hours because somehow my application does not create a claim field as it should.

@HenriquePombo I thought the role will be assigned by login automatically. Generally I have a Login which is assigned to a role by registration in Register.cshtml.cs.

```
string UserRole = Request.Form["RoleSelect"];
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
var result_CreateAsync = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
var result_AddToRolesAsync = await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, new[] { UserRole });
```

@HenriquePombo

I added the class like in tutorial explained

```
public class CustomUserFactory : AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteUserAccount>
{
    public CustomUserFactory(IAccessTokenProviderAccessor accessor)
        : base(accessor)
    {
    }
    public async override ValueTask<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateUserAsync(
        RemoteUserAccount account,
        RemoteAuthenticationUserOptions options)
    {
        var user = await base.CreateUserAsync(account, options);
        var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)user.Identity;
        if (account != null)
        {
            MapArrayClaimsToMultipleSeparateClaims(account, claimsIdentity);
        }
        return user;
    }
    private void MapArrayClaimsToMultipleSeparateClaims(RemoteUserAccount account, ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity)
    {
        foreach (var prop in account.AdditionalProperties)
        {
            var key = prop.Key;
            var value = prop.Value;
            if (value != null &&
                (value is JsonElement element && element.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Array))
            {
                claimsIdentity.RemoveClaim(claimsIdentity.FindFirst(prop.Key));
                var claims = element.EnumerateArray()
                    .Select(x => new Claim(prop.Key, x.ToString()));
                claimsIdentity.AddClaims(claims);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I added the service to the client Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization().AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomUserFactory>();
```

Comment: Where are you assigning the role? (The role is not added/created on startup, like if you think about it, that makes no sense; not sure if that was what you were thinking when saying "... added *code*").

Comment: Following your example, if the login is successfully you can read the roles the user has from the DB and then do "await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Data From DB");"

Comment: @HenriquePombo as shown in my edit I create a new user with a role. I can also see this in my database. I think when I log in with a user with a role, the role is automatically assigned if it is in the database.

Comment: I can't speak for webAssembly as I myself haven't used; but on my Blazor Server APP using Identity I still need to assign the roles manually. In your example, if you scroll to the line starting by "Once we have the Register page in our project," he's assigning the roles there (hard-coded, you would need to do it scalable/from DB).

Comment: @HenriquePombo like in my edit i added the clas in client i guess this is the point where the user should added a role from database. I'm right or confused here?

Comment: @HenriquePombo or otherway around, how do you assigning the roles manually in your solution?

Comment: https://github.com/BrianLParker/AuthApp Has rolls and policies. It also shows how to transform the multible roles into seperate role claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem myself. I will now give up programming forever and bury myself. It is a shame. Sooo... I have "Roles" instead of a single "Role" in the Register.html.cs. Differnt is:

```
_userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, UserRole )
```

and

```
await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, new[] { UserRole });
```

Now when I created a new user with this small difference, everything works fine.
Thx @HenriquePombo thank you very much for your time and advice.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you were not setting a role for the user in the first place? I have a role assigned to the user already, still, I am unable to get roles to work. "role" is not in the claims list just like in your question, however, in the database I can see that the role is assigned to a user.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind I was using Blazor Server so some things might differ (especially on startup, I would say). Also some specific things you could alter for the example you are using (for instance I'm using SessionStorage, etc.)

Also, I followed this Blazor Tutorial playlist [Blazor Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xr56fmgLl74&list=PL4WEkbdagHIR0RBe_P4bai64UDqZEbQap&index=1) for helping me with those kinds of things. Best regards.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
      ...
      //Allow the use of Authentication and Authorization in my program
      app.UseAuthentication();
      app.UseAuthorization();
}
```

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      ...
      //Service I added for handling authentication related stuff
      services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();
}
```

**Class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider**

```
public async Task MarkUserAsAuthenticated(UserModel user)
{
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.EmailAddress),
        new Claim(Claims.UserCredentials, user.UserCredentials),
    }, "apiauth_type");

    var roles = await GetUserRoles(user.UserCredentials);
    foreach(var role in roles)
    {
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Name));
    }

    var user1 = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

    NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user1)));

    foreach (var claim in identity.Claims)
    {
        await _sessionStorageService.SetItemAsStringAsync(claim.Type, claim.Value);
    }
}
```

and then somewhere:

```
private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _customAuthenticationStateProvider;
...
await ((CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)_customAuthenticationStateProvider).MarkUserAsAuthenticated(loginUser);
```

Comment: :D   We all have been there, and all of us will be there again sometime.